# A multi-threaded writer: concurrency issues using cpp

Tags: c++, concurrency

I am trying to build a library that would write to a single file, and would be able to work in a multi-threaded environment. The requirements are:

1. No concurrency problems will occur while writing to the file.
2. The order in which threads are handled is not important.
3. The library should be non blocking, i.e. the write and flush functions will return before the given buffer had been written.

Here's what I have so far:

```
int write2device(char *buffer, int length) {
    Task * task = new Task(id++,buffer,length);
    pthread_t * thread = new pthread_t;
    Argument * arg = new Argument; //A sturct with pthread_t and task fields
    arg->task = task;
    arg->thread = thread;
    pthread_create(thread,NULL,deamonWrite,arg);
    return 0;
}

void wait(Argument * arg) {
    //manager is a singleton class that handles the threads database and related
    //issues
    manager->pushDeamon(arg->thread);
    manager->lock(arg->task->getId()); //mutex - only one thread can write
}

void * deamonWrite(void * arg) {
    Argument * temp = (Argument *) arg;
    wait(temp);
    //critical section
    //will add signal() later
    return NULL;
}
```

The idea is that for every thread calling write2device I open a thread that runs deamonWrite(). This function has the structure of wait() -> critical section -> signal().
In wait, if someone else is writing I will (haven't done yet) suspend the thread so that the user won't wait till it's done writing.

I have two questions:

1. How do I implement the mutex (lock function)? I understand that This must be an atomic function, sense several threads trying to acquire a lock might result in chaos.
2. Is my general structure in the right way?

I am new to concurrency and would appreciate any thoughts on this matter - thanks!

Comment: You should add the tag corresponding to the language you use (C or C++ it seems). It will attract more views => more answers.

Comment: You'd be better off pushing the `Task` structures to a queue/vector and processing them sequentially from a single thread instead of multiple threads for each task individually. The only place where you'll need a mutex is when pushing to the queue.

Comment: @IRobot, that is a good answer

Comment: @Ben, do you mean I should post it as an answer? It only addresses the second of his two questions, so I thought a comment to be more appropriate.

Comment: I would recommend getting familiar with the (Unix I assume) threads API, like here: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#MutexOverview             Who is your teacher? Concurrency is a very deep subject.

Comment: same question as Digital... How deep is your API? Can you use posix library? Are you implementing your own user threads? etc...

Comment: @IRobot, yes post that as an answer. For section 1, he should use a mutex object from his platform library whatever that is. CRITICAL_SECTION on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Push the `Task` structures to a queue/vector and process them sequentially from a single thread instead of multiple threads for each task individually. The only place where you'll need a mutex is when pushing to and pulling from the queue. As Ben correctly noted in the comments, you should leave the implementation of thread synchronization primitives (mutex, critical section) to the OS and/or whatever system API you're allowed to use.

Comment: The correct approach, by far.  Creating a new thread for every write is just such a bad idea that I wonder where it came from.  Somewhere out there is a textbook, or set of same, that says 'To use threads, you must create one with your data as a parameter, let it run and then let it terminate by returning. For bonus marks, use 'join' to add even more overhead to your app'.  Will someone please collect all these textbooks and burn them, preferably piled around stakes with the authors tied to them.